# Как задать приоритет прокрутики EditText внутри ViewPager2?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, edittext

Есть `ViewPager2` с 4 фрагментами, делал по документации. Внутри одного из фрагментов расположен `EditText`, но когда текста слишком много, он уходит за края, и чтобы его посмотреть надо сделать свайп. Но когда я делаю свайп в области `EditText`, его перехватывает `ViewPager2`. Как можно этого избежать?

Comment: вы хоть код покажите, скрин того как поле уходит за края, очень сложно понять где именно проблема

Comment: Да не поле уходит за края, а текст в нём, когда его много) И я хотел бы унать, как реализовать прокрутку этого EditText, чтобы посмотреть текст в нём, который скрылся из виду, но свайпы перехватывает ViewPager2, и я перехожу на другой фрагмент :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прокрутку у поля ввода можно сделать таким образом в `xml`:

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical" 
android:overScrollMode="always"
```

либо в коде класса:

```
EditText dwEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DwEdit);

 dwEdit.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (view.getId() ==R.id.DwEdit) {
                        view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        switch (event.getAction()&MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что ViewPager перехватывает действие, и прокручивается фрагмент, а не EditText :(

Comment: А хотя я щас попробовал - заработало! Спасибо!

Comment: А вот ещё вопрос, может быть не по теме, но можно ли сделать эту прокрутку с ускорением, типо свайпнул пальцем, прокрутка ускорилась и медленно теряя скорость останавливается? :)

Comment: можно я думаю, но это нужно будет писать самому анимационный файл и подключать его, если найду что-то по данному подпункту то отредактирую ответ :)